# Codeigniter get_where with 'or' in array of conditions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im trying to get values of 'yrlvl' with 11 or 1112 values but i cant get it whit this line of code:

```
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('subjects', array('strand' => 'GAS', 'yrlvl' => '11'or '1112'));
        return $query->result_array();
```

I'm only getting the 1112 value someone help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some possible solutions:

**Solution 1:**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('subjects');
$this->db->where('strand', 'GAS');
$where = '(yrlvl = "11" or yrlvl = "1112")'; // make a OR statement by passing values here
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

**Solution 2:**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('subjects');
$this->db->where('strand', 'GAS');
$where = array('11', '1112'); // make an array of values for OR condition
$this->db->where_in('yrlvl', $where);
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```